# protobuf, How to travel all set fields in a protobuf message which I dont know in detail?(C++)

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I want to travel the field has been set in a unknown protobuf message.
I tried

```
for (int i = 0; i < chk_des->field_count(); ++i) {
    const ::google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor* chk_field = chk_des->field(i);
    (do somethin...)
}
```

It just travel all field. I want to travel setted field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You retrieve a reflection object:

```
virtual const Reflection * 
    Message::GetReflection() const
```

> Get the Reflection interface for this Message, which can be used to
>   read and modify the fields of the Message dynamically (in other words,
>   without knowing the message type at compile time).

After that you can use for example:

```
virtual bool Reflection::HasField(const Message & message, const FieldDescriptor * field) const = 0
```

> Check if the given non-repeated field is set.

So notice that you also need to pass the field descriptor from your code snippet.

```
const FieldDescriptor * 
    Descriptor::field(
        int index) const
```

> Gets a field by index, where 0 <= index < field_count().
>
> These are returned in the order they were defined in the .proto file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works. `bool Reflection::HasField()` is the key.